# How to make Exception handling Loop (Unlimited amount of times)

Tags: java, loops, methods

Responses to previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487706/try-and-catch-block-not-functioning-in-user-defined-method) , my initial answer to that question had been solved, but I had another problem when it came down to looping which was later solved by simply using a for loop.

However, my problem is I do not want the user to constantly have to restart the program after an exception is handled, rather I want it to loop the same beginning questions to the user. I've tried placing print statements after the return statements, and also tried completely copying the logic code after the try catch, however, realizing that that would not cause the user to loop unlimited times for the exception. Also, on a side note yes my previous question had good answers, however, no one managed to answer my more recurring problem, which is why no one got the check mark towards their answer.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        double x;
        x = circlemethods(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    }

    public static double circlemethods(double volume, double surfacearea,
            double area, double radius) throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String numInput;
        String reqInput;
        String amountStr;
        double numInt = 0;
        double num = 0;
        double answer = 0;
        double amount = 0;
        double answer2 = 0;
        double answer3 = 0;
        double answer4 = 0;

        for (double i = 0; i < 999; i++)
            ;
        try
        {

            // for (double i = 0; i < 999; i++);

            // while (numInt != 999) {

            System.out.println("This program will ask for a given user radius, then proceed to calculate the user input");
            System.out.println("The program will use four methods to achieve this, all calling back to the main method");
            System.out.println("Press any key to continue");
            numInput = myInput.readLine();

            System.out.println("First, what would you like to calculate?");
            System.out.println("Enter '1' for Circumference, '2' for area, '3' for volume, or '4' for surface area");
            reqInput = myInput.readLine();
            numInt = Double.parseDouble(reqInput);

            System.out.println("Now enter the radius of the required shape(Half of diameter)");
            numInput = myInput.readLine();
            num = Double.parseDouble(numInput);

            DecimalFormat nextAmount = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            amountStr = nextAmount.format(amount);

            if (numInt == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose to calculate circumference, given the radius :" + num);
                answer = (3.14) * (2) * (num);
                System.out.print("The circumference of that sphere is :");
                System.out.println(answer + "cm³");
                return answer;
            }
            else if (numInt == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose to calculate area, given the radius :" + num);
                answer2 = (3.14) * 2;
                System.out.print("The area of the circle is :");
                System.out.println(answer2 + "cm²");
                return answer2;
            }
            else if (numInt == 3)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose to calculate volume, given the radius :" + num);
                answer3 = 4 / 3 * (3.14) * (num) * (3) * (3) * (3);
                System.out.print("The volume of that sphere is : cm³");
                System.out.println(answer3 + "cm³");
                return answer3;
            }
            else
            // if (numInt == 4)
            {
                System.out.println("You chose to calculate surface area, given the radius :" + num);
                answer4 = 4 * (3.14) * (num) * (2) * (2);
                System.out.print("The Surface area of that sphere is :");
                System.out.println(answer4 + "cm²");
                return answer4;

            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Please do not enter any string values, next time input enter a number ");
            return 0;
            // how to loop this untill the user inputs a number????

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to improve your code formatting as it is very difficult to read and understand your code as it is written. This is particularly important when asking others to help you with this code. Consider creating a method for getting input, having a while loop in the method and not return from the method unless the input is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you use a `while(true)` loop instead of looping for 999 times. (That loop doesn't actually do anything considering there is a semicolon right after it.)

Then, you remove the `return 0;` from your `catch` block.

So it would be

```
while(true) {
    try {
        .... //your code
    }
catch {...}
} //while loop end bracket
```

This way, the loop will only end if it reaches one of your return statements.

Comment: Both answers were correct, but I do respect your effort and Memento's effort as well, however,yours was the quickest to work, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop until you get a valid value. One way to do that is loop until a boolean value is set to true. Try something similar to this:

```
boolean inputIsValid = false;
while (!inputIsValid) { ...
```

Then when you have determined you have a valid input, add the line:

```
inputIsValid = true;
```

Your loop will continue until inputIsValid becomes true.

You could also create an endless while loop. Then when you receive a valid input, `break` out of the loop:

```
while(true) {
    //when valid input is received
    break;
}
```